# How can I convert date string to time string?

Tags: swift, date, time, nsdateformatter

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"date": "2022-06-30T02:15:00.000+07:00"
```

And I formatted it to convert to "HH:mm" like this:

```
func formatTime(string: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"

    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    let date: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: string)
    return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date ?? Date())
}
```

The result I want it returns is 09:15, but it returns 02:15.
Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Thank you

Comment: well it will always return the DateFormatter's timezone (current if you don't set it) regardless of the string timezone

Comment: `"2022-06-30T02:15:00.000+07:00"` is the same as `"2022-06-29T19:15:00.000+00:00"`

Answer (score 0):

"2022-06-30T02:15:00.000+07:00" is the date in the time zone plus 7 hours from the UTC time zone. Than this date in UTC is “ 2022-06-29T19:15:00Z”

while dateFormatterPrint has a default locale configuration according to the phone settings

You need to set UTC timezone

Comment: No the real date in UTC is the day before at 19:15 `2022-06-29 19:15:00 +0000` if He were located in UTC timezone it should return `"19:15"`. His timezone is GMT+7 same as the date string

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, you right. I have set dateFormatterPrint.timeZone = Timezone.current, and it returns 19:15. when I set TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+14") it returns right. But I don't understand why

Comment: @DaggTuan I am not sure why would you expect it to return `9:15`. It returns the correct time "7:15 pm" of the day before June 29th which is the same point in time at your current timezone for "2:15 am" of June 30th at UTC (+0000) which is 7 hours behind your timezone. In other words when it is 2:15 am at your location it is 7:15 pm in England (day before)

Comment: Because in website they return 9:15, so I want to return the same result. Maybe data is wong

Comment: What website? Can you post the link or a screen shot?  Your date string clearly states 2:15 AM at your location (+07:00). Why would you expect another time? Again the correct result using current location if you your timezone is plus 7 hours is 2:15 AM period.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might want to convert the DateTime to your local time first: 
**Convert To LocalTime:**

```
func utcToLocal(dateStr: String) -> String? {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
  dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
  if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  }
  return nil
}
```

And then:

```
let utcTime = formatTime(string: "2022-06-30T02:15:00.000+07:00")
let localTime = utcToLocal(dateStr: utcTime)
print(localTime)
```

The Result:

```
09:15
```

I hope this help you solve your problem.

Comment: This is wrong. A date has no timezone. Date is a point in time. Btw there is no "problem". OP is clearly misunderstanding the date string.