# Swift Convert String to Date

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I have a string with time in it `"20:52"` and I am trying to use `DateFormatter` to convert it to `Date`.

My code is:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
var dateFromStr = dateFormatter.date(from:"20:52")!
print("dateFromStr: \(dateFromStr)")
```

And the result printed is: `dateFromStr: 2000-01-02 02:52:00 +0000` but I would expect it to be `dateFromStr: 2000-01-02 20:52:00 +0000`

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your current locale UTC/GMT/+0000?  If not, the `Date` is showing the time based on what it would be @ UTC/GMT/+0000 when compared to your current `Locale` - remember, dumping the `Date` in this manner is just going to present debug information

Comment: For example, if I run your code locally, it prints `2000-01-01 09:52:00 +0000`, but I'm +11 hours in front of GMT

Comment: I see what you are saying now that makes sense. I think I was under the impression I could simply convert the string to a `Date` object representation that would always give the time in the string no matter the time zone. So I guess I need to set the `Locale` to be UTC/GMT/+0000?

Comment: I would be careful with "dumping" `Date` values and instead, make use of a `DateFormatter` for format the output the way you want it (including the locale presentation).  If you set the `DateFormatter`s locale to UTC/GMT, you'd end up with a time representation based on that locale, which probably isn't what you really want

Comment: For example, if I add `print(dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr))` to your code, it prints `20:52`

Comment: Ultimately I want to do some math with the date though such as add to it with addingTimeInterval() so I don't just want to print out the date. Sorry should have clarified that in the question.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, remember, the `description` func is just a debug output.  So long as your inputs are in the same TZ, it should work just fine.  Having said that, if the TZ is unimportant, then using UTC/GMT isn't a bad idea - but that all comes to down context

Comment: Maybe this thread is relate to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72809973/how-can-i-convert-date-string-to-time-string/72810408?noredirect=1#comment128604952_72810408
Hope this help you.

Comment: `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")` did the trick!